# Pasting into terminal, two steps vs one step

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, console, paste

This is a weird problem -- for pasting text into terminal, I've seen two types of behaviors, two steps vs one step, and I had never figured out why.

Let me start with the *"one step"* behavior, it is as normal as you can think of. Pasting in multiple-line texts will behave just like they are typed in, nothing special at all.

As for the *"two step"* behavior, the pasted text are shown in revers color:

[image]

and it needs me to press return for the pasting to actually happen:

[image]

Moreover, sometimes the pasted text will somehow stays in the revers-color stage, making the visual clue completely out of order:

[image]

How to get rid of the two-step behavior and get back to the one-step one?

```
$ uname -rm
5.10.0-6-amd64 x86_64

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid
Release:        testing
Codename:       bullseye
```

Comment: The answer under the linked duplicate is good for Zsh or Bash. If your shell is neither Zsh nor Bash and the answer does not answer your question then please [edit] the question and tell us what your shell is. Then leave me a comment, I will reopen.

Comment: It's good. I'm using Bash. thx @KamilMaciorowski.